# Button event with jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using some jQuery in my example to trigger a button to start the . Unfourtunately my script isn't working. What am i missing here?

**Clicking #button should start the #zoomin animation from #cam**

Thank's for your help.

```
<body bgcolor="#060e19">

 <a-scene>

      <a-entity  camera="userHeight: 1.6" look-controls wasd-controls position="0 20 5" rotation="-80 0 0">
          <a-animation id="cam" attribute="position" begin="#zoomin" dur="3000" easing="ease-out" to="0 2 6"></a-animation>
      <a-entity cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500; max-distance: 30;"
          id="cursor"
          position="0 0 -.8"
          geometry="primitive: ring; radius-inner: .01; radius-outer: .015;"
          material="color: black; shader: flat">
      </a-entity>
      </a-entity>

      <a-entity id="button" geometry="primitive: box; width: 1; height: .3; depth: .02;" material="color: #3F3F3F;" position="0 20 4" rotation="-60 0 0"
        event-set__1="_event: mouseenter; material.color: #737373; scale: 1.03 1.03 1.03"
        event-set__2="_event: mouseleave; material.color: #3F3F3F; scale: 1 1 1;">
      </a-entity>

      <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -1" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
      <a-box position="-1 0.5 1" rotation="0 45 0" width="1" height="1" depth="1"  color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
      <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 1" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
      <a-plane rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>

      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
      <a-entity position="0 0 3.8">
        <a-camera></a-camera>
      </a-entity>
</a-scene>   
</body>

<script>

   document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', function() {
   document.querySelector('#cam').emit('zoomin');
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: you're using the # sign as part of your selector. This is straight javascript and not jquery. So drop the # sign and it should work

Comment: document.querySelector('#button') should be like document.querySelector('button')   and   document.querySelector('#cam') shold be like document.querySelector('cam')

Answer (score 0):

Events can be created with the `Event` constructor:

```
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var zoomin = new Event('zoomin');
  document.querySelector('#cam').dispatchEvent(zoomin);
});
```

Comment: Unfourtunately it's still not reacting.